# Why am I getting -8 while printing res value instead 0,-1,1 as compareTo method returns those values?

Tags: java, string

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int len;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.next();
        String B=sc.next();
        len=A.length() + B.length();
        System.out.println(len);
        int res=A.compareTo(B);
        System.out.println(res);
        switch(res)
            {
            case 0:System.out.println("Equal");break;
            case -1:System.out.println("No");break;
            case 1:System.out.println("Yes");break;
            }
    }
}
```

Why am i getting -8 while printing res value instead 0,-1,1 as compareTo method returns those values.?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  Maybe this question has nothing to do at all with `Scanner` but just with a basic misunderstanding of method `compareTo()`

Comment: @martinhh: You may well be right. Or it may be a both/and. :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Why am i getting -8 while printing res value instead 0,-1,1 as
>   compareTo method returns those values.?

This is not true.

What String#compareTo returns is:

> **the value 0** if the argument string is equal to this string; **a value
>   less than 0** if this string is lexicographically less than the string
>   argument; **and a value greater than 0** if this string is
>   lexicographically greater than the string argument.

See from Javadocs of [String#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a
>   negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the
>   argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String
>   object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is
>   zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the
>   equals(Object) method would return true.
>
> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are
>   different, then either they have different characters at some index
>   that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are
>   different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more
>   index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string
>   whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by
>   using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In
>   this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character
>   values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:

```
this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
```

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter
>   string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case,
>   compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that
>   is, the value:

```
 this.length()-anotherString.length()
```

Hope this helps.